# What is the name for the 'object' of a middle voice?

Tags: grammar, terminology, syntactic-analysis, middle-voice

In the sentence 'John weighed the letter', *the letter* is the direct object of the predicate *weighed*.
In the sentence 'The letter was blue', *blue* is a predicative nominal.

In the sentence 'The letter weighed 2 oz.', what function does *2 oz.* have?

- I wouldn't say it is a predicative nominal, because *weighed* is not a linking verb.
- I wouldn't say it is a direct object, because *weighed*, here, is used in a detransitivized  verb: this sentence has a different structure than 'John weighed the letter'.

This problem arises, in my view, because weighs appears in the middle voice here. Hence my question: what is the name for the 'object' of a middle voice?

<sub>Examples were taken from R.C. Benton, 2009: [Aspect and the Biblical Hebrew](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/36168), p. 162.</sub>

Comment: As John Lawler says, it's a _measure phrase_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks! I think I didn't find that question because it didn't mention middle voice.

Comment: No problem. I have the sort of memory that retains what my wife calls trivia (rather than important things like whose turn it is to wash up, say). I think 'male' describes it. And some of the previous material here certainly takes some finding; question titles can be bemusing.

Comment: Just for fun, we weighed some different objects and noted the results. the objects included a spade, a lump of lead, a letter and a flange-warbler. 

The spade weighed 12lbs. The lump was 3lbs. The letter was 2oz. The flange-warbler was a boojum.

How is the description of the weighed letter not grammatically the same as the description of the coloured letter, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin *weigh* is not a linking verb, so it cannot have a predicative nominal. See the question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks Camil and the question this was a duplicate of didn't specifically address the issue…

I was trying to look not at "weighed" but at "was".

Could you address "The letter was 2oz", please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin ah, I see, apologies. In that case I would think it is like *blue*, yes. But I'm in no way an expert. If you want to be sure, consider opening a new question :)